# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Busy indicator remains displayed in AppCenter client

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

After [successfully building the AppCenter client application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427310/ibm-worklight-6-0-app-center-on-ios7-fails-to-open) and launching it in an iOS device, my problem is that when I enter my Worklight Server credentials, the server URL and the port and with or without the applicationcenter context, the loading progress keeps running...

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried accessing the console from the iOS emulator with dev tools turned on? You might be able to see some potential errors from there. You can also check your server logs as well. I know that sometimes, when a 500 error occurs in WL, the code sent to stop the indicator is never invoked, so that's why you'd get that behavior. Honestly, I'm somewhat new to WL myself, just going on regular ol' web dev experience.

Comment: To respond to the advice of Zarazthuztra. We followed your advice but we don't get an error from the server side. We have the impression that the Mobile App, it selves keeps running. Nothing seems to be transferred to the App Server.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Idan, first thing to do is to run the application center client on the iOS emulator and look at the device logs. I have seen the loading never ending when the client was not compiled correctly, note that the native folder of the application center client worklight project contains native code (a cordova plugin) that needs to be present in order for the application to run properly. If this is the problem you are facing, the cordova log will tell you that the plugin named 'com.ibm.mobile.InstallerPlugin' is missing.